# LINQ with two groupings

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I am struggling with a double grouping using C#/LINQ on data similar in shape to the following example. I'm starting with a list of TickItems coming from the data layer, and I have now got it shaped as such:

`TickItem {
      ItemName: string;
      QtyNeeded: int;
      QtyFulfilled: int;
      Category: string;
}`

```
List<TickItem> items = new List<TickItem>();
items.Add("apple", 1, 0, "food");
items.Add("orange", 1, 1, "food");
items.Add("orange", 1, 0, "food");
items.Add("bicycle", 1, 1, "vehicle");
items.Add("apple", 1, 1, "food");
items.Add("apple", 1, 0, "food");
items.Add("car", 1, 1, "vehicle");
items.Add("truck", 1, 0, "vehicle");
items.Add("banana", 1, 0, "food");
```

I need to group this data by Category, with the sum of each numeric column in the end result. In the end, it should be shaped like this:

```
{ "food":    { "apple"  : 3, 1 },
             { "banana" : 1, 0 },
             { "orange" : 2, 1 } },
{ "vehicle": { "bicycle": 1, 1 },
             { "car"    : 1, 1 },
             { "truck"  : 1, 0} }
```

I have been able to do each of the groupings individually (group by ItemName and group by Category), but I have not been able to perform both groupings in a single LINQ statement. My code so far:

```
var groupListItemName = things.GroupBy(tiλ => tiλ.ItemName).ToList();
var groupListCategory = things.GroupBy(tiλ => tiλ.Category).ToList();
```

Can anyone help?

[edit: I can use either method or query syntax, whichever is easier to visualize the process with]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = from i in items
            group i by i.Category into categoryGroup
            select new
            {
               Category = categoryGroup.Key,
               Items = categoryGroup.GroupBy(g => g.ItemName)
                                    .Select(g => new
                                    {
                                        ItemName = g.Key,
                                        QtyNeeded = g.Sum(x => x.QtyNeeded),
                                        QtyFulfilled = g.Sum(x => x.QtyFulfilled)
                                    }).ToList()
            };
```

This query will return sequence of anonymous objects representing items grouped by category. Each category object will have list of anonymous objects, which will contain totals for each item name.

```
foreach(var group in query)
{
    // group.Category
    foreach(var item in group.Items)
    {
        // item.ItemName
        // item.QtyNeeded
        // item.QtyFulfilled 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at this post.

http://sohailnedian.blogspot.com/2012/12/linq-groupby-with-aggregate-functions.html

Multiple grouping can be done via new keyword.

```
empList.GroupBy(_ => new { _.DeptId, _.Position })  
    .Select(_ => new  
    {  
        MaximumSalary = _.Max(deptPositionGroup => deptPositionGroup.Salary),  
        DepartmentId = _.Key.DeptId,  
        Position = _.Key.Position  
    }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

[`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx) has an overload that lets you specify result transformation, for example:

```
var result = items.GroupBy(i => i.Category,
    (category, categoryElements) => new
    {   
        Category = category,
        Elements = categoryElements.GroupBy(i => i.ItemName,
            (item, itemElements) => new 
            {
                Item = item,
                QtyNeeded = itemElements.Sum(i => i.QtyNeeded),
                QtyFulfilled = itemElements.Sum(i => i.QtyFulfilled)
            })
    });
```